# Azure.Storage.Blobs get name of file when download file from SAS link instead full path to file

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have file into Azure Blob Storage, container name = `app-files`, and path to the file = `/files/{guid}/1.docx`
I have the following code to get SAS link to that file:

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("con_string");
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("app-files");
BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(path);

var blobSasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder
                {
                    StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                    BlobContainerName = blobClient.BlobContainerName,
                    BlobName = blobClient.Name
                };

blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

var storageSharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential("account_name", "account_key");

BlobSasQueryParameters sasQueryParameters = blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(storageSharedKeyCredential);

var url = blobClient.Uri.ToString() + "?" + sasQueryParameters.ToString();

return url;
```

This code works fine but downloaded file name = `files_{guid}_1.docx`, it seems it show full path to file but replace "/" with "_". I would like to see just file name = `1.docx` .

Can I change downloaded file name somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with changing one line of code from:

```
var url = blobClient.Uri.ToString() + "?" + sasQueryParameters.ToString();
```

to:

```
var url = blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("%2F", "/").ToString() + "?" + sasQueryParameters.ToString();
```